# Reference a global JS function in another file, in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

What I'm actually doing is writing a VS Code Extension, but since I'm new to Node I'm struggling with referencing one JS file from another.

```
//main.js (compiled from TypeScript)

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
require("./Test.js");
console.log("hello");
t1();
```

and

```
//Test.js

function t1() {
    console.log("t1");
}
```

They're both in the same folder.  If I run it from VS Code, or from node directly, it doesn't work

```
PS E:\VSCodeTest> node src/main.js
hello
E:\VSCodeTest\src\main.js:5
t1();
^

ReferenceError: t1 is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\VSCodeTest\src\main.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:676:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

The VS Code project is actually TypeScript but I've distilled it down to the crux of the problem in the JS files.

I believe it should work based on

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html

> Import a module for side-effects only Though not recommended practice,
>   some modules set up some global state that can be used by other
>   modules. These modules may not have any exports, or the consumer is
>   not interested in any of their exports. To import these modules, use:
>
> import "./my-module.js";

How have I misunderstood that?

Comment: `t1` needs to be exported from `Test.js` so that any other file can then import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `Test.js` to this:

```
//Test.js

function t1() {
    console.log("t1");
}

module.exports = t1;
```

And then do something more like this in `main.js`:

```
const t1 = require("./Test.js");
t1(); // prints "t1"
```

There's a lot of information about how modules work in the docs: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html

Alternatively, if you want `t1` to be a global, then assign it to `global.t1` in `Test.js`:

```
//Test.js

global.t1 = function t1() {
    console.log("t1");
};
```

I wouldn't recommend that if you can avoid it, though, for all the reasons people recommend avoiding globals when possible

Answer (score 1):

Require doesn't work quite like that, but you're close -- if you want to use a function you've created to in another file, just add it to that file's exports.

```
/// test.js
exports.t1 = function() ...

// or

module.exports = {
  t1: function() ...
}
```

Then you need to specifically save that off to use it

```
/// main.js
var t1 = require('./test.js').t1;

t1();
```

Global scoping doesn't work like it does in the browser, check out [node's docs](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html) on it, or [try a blog explaining it](http://stackabuse.com/using-global-variables-in-node-js/)  (I didn't write this and can't fully vouch)